# How to chose appropriate radius for ball in an open set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_e)$ be the metric space with Euclidean metric and $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set with a form of the open square. Using definition of open sets via balls on $S$, how shall I chose radius $r$ of the ball $B(p, r)$ for every point $p\in S$?

Comment: Small enough to make $B(p,r)\subseteq S$ a true statement. The set $S$ is open if and only such an $r$ is available for each $p\in S$.

Comment: One does not necessarily have the same $r$ for all points $p\in S$.  Indeed it will depend on how close $p4 is to the boundary of $S$ (the four edges of the "open square").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider distance to the complement of S, by definition that is the minimum distance $d$ to any point outside S. Then you may take half of the distance and you'll be okay. (If any point outside S was in the ball $S(p, d/2)$, then ${\rm dist}(p, S^C) \le d/2$, which is a contradiction if $d \ne 0$.)